# How to tell Gradle not to exclude .so files in my .jar dependency?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I have a `.jar` dependency which comes with `.so` library inside it.

```
library.jar
       |
       -----com/company
              |
              -----.class files
       -----libs
              |
              -----libX.so
```

The jar makes use of this `.so` library internally, and I'm building an Android app that makes use of the jar.

Everything is good until after I build the apk : by exploring it using 7zip, I discover that the `.so` files have disappeared, leading to all sorts of errors when using the app.

So is there any way to tell Gradle not to exclude the `.so` files when building? I don't want to copy them manually into a folder in my Android Project, since I'm not using them directly, but the `.jar` library is the one loading them.

Edit 1 : Adding `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/lib1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/lib2.jar')
}
```

**Edit 2 : Here is the solution following the previous suggestions of @shizhen**

1- My `.jar` included the `.so` files in `libs` directory. I had to rename that to `lib`.

2- I unpacked the `.jar` to gather the `.so` files.

3- I created `src/jniLibs` folder and put the `.so` files, each in its respective `<ANDROID_ABI>` folder.

4- I modified the `build.gradle` file to include :

```
android {
...
sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/jniLibs'
        }
    }
}
```

5 - Et voila! The final `.apk` now includes the native libraries.

Comment: What does your Gradle build look like, or at least the relevant parts?

Comment: @Chriki I have added my build.gradle

Comment: What is your library including .so files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything is good until after I build the apk : by exploring it using 7zip, I discover that the .so files have disappeared, leading to all sorts of errors when using the app.

I believe your jar dependency was **not originally for android** but generally for Java.

Android app uses **.dex** format, so all your **.jar** dependencies will be repackaged into one or more dex files. You **.so** files won't be used as it is inside the jar.

> So is there any way to tell Gradle not to exclude the .so files when building? I don't want to copy them manually into a folder in my Android Project, since I'm not using them directly, but the .jar library is the one loading them.

So, in order to adapt your jar to Android app, you **HAVE TO** unzip the jar taking out all the **.so** files and **manually** put them into `src/jniLibs/<ANDROID_ABI>/`, e.g.

```
jniLibs
    ├── arm64-v8a
    │   ├── libxxx.so
    │   └── libyyy.so
    ├── armeabi-v7a
    │   ├── libxxx.so
    │   └── libyyy.so
    ├── x86
    │   ├── libxxx.so
    │   └── libyyy.so
    └── x86_64
        ├── libxxx.so
        └── libyyy.so
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The ```.jar``` dependency was written using Java SE, but includes native ```.so``` libs Android ABIs.

The ```.jar``` has these ```.so``` libraries inside folders called ```libs/<ANDROID_ABI>/```. It then extracts them into temporary folders to load them using ```System.load()```.

Having no control over the code in ```.jar```, adding the libraries manually to ```src/jniLibs/<ANDROID_ABI>/``` won't solve the problem since the code in the ```.jar``` expects to find them in its ```libs/<ANDROID_ABI>/``` folders. 

Is there any other way or is this hopeless?

Comment: Jar is nothing but zip file, take out the .so files and put it in jniLibs will work, this is how I do for JNA library which is same case as yours

Comment: Be sure that your project configured the jniLibs path correctly. You can analyze your final apk using Android Studio to double check the .so is packaged

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I will edit my answer to clarify how I dealt with the situation, but I basically followed your answer, edited the build.gradle file and renamed the ```libs``` directory inside the ```.jar``` to ```lib```.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess based on the Android docs on [“Shrink your code and resources”](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code): it seems that ProGuard is automatically used for release builds, in order to remove apparently unused code. You could try to disable that:

```
// …
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
        }
    }
// …
```

If that helps, then ProGuard would be your culprit. Instead of leaving it disabled, you could then try to explicitly [tell it to keep the files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code) that must not be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was really hoping this would help but it didn't. It seems the problem comes from the DEX format of Android not repackaging the ```.so``` files from the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set your sourceSets in build.gradle(Module: app)

```
android {
   ...
   ...
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = [
                './src/main/jniLibs'
        ]
    }
 }
}
```

Use ndk if your project requried:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```